# Preserve a value of an element after change using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internationalization

For internationalization support, I wrote code that changes the URL from `#lang-select` dropdown .The code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var sel = document.getElementById('lang-select');
    sel.onchange = function(){window.location.replace($('#lang-select').val());};
 });
```

the above code works fine and it changes the URL from `http://0.0.0.0:3000/fr` to `http://0.0.0.0:3000/en`. 
Now I want to preserve the changed value, but without success. I have written the code below. I don't know why it is wrong/not working .

```
function langSelect(){
var available_languages = {
    "en":"English",
    "de":"Deutsch",
    "ru" :"Россию",
    "fr" : "Française"
};
var languageInUrl= document.URL.split("/")[3];
for(var shortLanguage in available_languages){
    if(shortLanguage === languageInUrl) {
        var langaugeOptionArray = $("#lang-select>option");
        for(var i = 0 ; langaugeOptionArray.length > i ; i++){
            if(langaugeOptionArray[i].label === available_languages[shortLanguage]){
                langaugeOptionArray[i].selected = true;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Please tell me what's wrong in above code and since what I am doing is not a new thing, please share what is the best practice to overcome this scenario.

Currently, I am using backend to accomplish this.

Comment: why are you not selecting/binding the event with jQuery?

Comment: the topmost code was written by another developer and i dont want to touch his code.So i write my own code`langSelect()`.Anyway,you please share your approach .

Comment: @mplungjan because it throws error. `TypeError: Property 'text' of object #<HTMLOptionElement> is not a function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  $('#lang-select').on("change",function(){   
    window.location.replace($(this).val());
  }); 
});

function langSelect(){
  var available_languages = {
    "en":"English",
    "de":"Deutsch",
    "ru" :"Россию",
    "fr" : "Française"
  };
  var languageInUrl= document.URL.split("/")[3];
  var lang = available_languages[languageInUrl];
  if (lang) {
    var langaugeOptionArray = $("#lang-select>option");
    langaugeOptionArray.each(function() {
      if($(this).text() === lang){
        $("#lang-select").val(lang);
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I believe we can even do

```
if (lang) {
  var opt = $("#lang-select").find('option[text="'+lang+'"]').val();
  if (opt) $("#lang-select").val(opt); 
}
```

Good luck

Comment: fantastic . Your code is clean and optimized . I liked `var lang = available_languages[languageInUrl];`this approach . Thanks